# ¿Hay alguna relación entre cuerda (adjetivo) y cuerda (sustantivo)?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, adjetivos, sustantivos

Una persona sana mentalmente se dice "persona cuerda".

Una persona a la que se le llame "loco" se le puede decir "está loco de atar".
Y las cosas se atan, por ejemplo, con *cuerdas*.

> ¿Una persona **cuerda** es un loco **atado**?

No conozco la etimología de esas palabras y no sé si puede haber relación en la raíz latina o si es una mera y divertida casualidad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hasta donde puedo llegar:

- el sustantivo *cuerda* procede del latín *chorda*, este del griego
  *jordá* y este del protoindoeuropeo * *ǵʰer* (intestino)
- el adjetivo *cuerda* procede el latín *cor* (corazón), este del griego *kardia* y este del protoindoeuropeo * *ḱḗr*

Por tanto, estas palabras no tienen una relación etimológica directa, aunque es curioso que las dos derivan de partes del cuerpo. El adjetivo, porque durante mucho tiempo se creyó que la mente residía en el corazón; el sustantivo, por analogía con la forma de las tripas de los animales.

Comment: "la mente residía en el corazón" hasta que descubrimos que el cerebro es el unico órgano que sabe que es un órgano xD Gracias por la respuesta :D a ver qué más se puede sacar de esta relación (si se puede)

Comment: Que hayas llegado al protoindoeuropeo significa que llegaste lo más atrás que se puede ir.

Comment: @Rodrigo Cierto. Lo que quería decir es que ya no sé si entre esas dos raíces indoeuropeas hay alguna relación, más allá de un parecido fonético (probablemente no lo sepa nadie), o si una palabra ha podido influir en la otra en su formación. Esto último es habitual, aunque lo es más en palabras con significados relacionados, cosa que aquí no parece.